# ¿Cómo convertir un dato numérico (como int, float, long) a char*?

Tags: c++, windows

Me gustaría un código o función simple para poder convertir un tipo de dato numérico (como `int`, `float`, `long`) a un `char*` para después concatenarlo con otro `char*`.

Utilizo como IDE codeblocks y como sistema operativo Windows.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Edit:

He intentado usar sprintf pero no funciona:

```
int o=10;
char* text;
    sprintf(text, "%i", o);
    cout<<text;
```

Ese codigo no hace nada al parecer

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado? y ¿qué es lo que deseas obtener? puedes hacer simplemente `char* a = &entero;`, `char a = (char)(entero); char* b = &a;`, etc... En cada caso obtienes un `char*` a partir de un dato numérico, sin embargo el resultado es drásticamente diferente en cada opción.

Comment: Deseo obtener un char* con un numero proporcionado por un tipo de dato numerico

Comment: Sigue ambigua la pregunta, pero por tu código puedo suponer que quieres obtener el texto que representa un número, como "7" si el número es `7`, ¿cierto? Dejando eso a un lado ¿porqué usar `char*` y no `std::string` como recomienda el estándard de C++?

Comment: Estas correcto en lo de 7 y"7"

Comment: Y en lo de string en lugar de char* es por esto:(error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'void*' for argument '1' to 'int was::winp(void*)'|), nesito un char* para asignarlo a un void*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realmente necesitas un `char *`, entonces despues de utilizar `ostringstream`, puedes construir un `char*` de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
int o = 10;
std::ostringstream streamTemp;
streamTemp << o;
    
char * myChar = new char[streamTemp.str().length() + 1];
strcpy(myChar, streamTemp.str().c_str());

// Algoritmo que utiliza a myChar

delete[] myChar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si se usa `sprintf`, el problema es que tu puntero no apunta a nada. Seria preferible si usas un `char[]`.

```
int o=10;
char text[15];
sprintf(text, "%i", o);
```

O si estas usando C++, seria mejor si usas:

```
int o = 10;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 10;
std::string text = ss.str();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, me guiaré por sprintf ya que nesesito un char, no un string,  solo tengo un problema con sprintf y es que si asignó a mi variable text una palabra como "Hola" al asignarle el valor de o con sprintf, se pierden todos los dato guardados anteriormente, cómo podría asignar un valor de tipo int sin perder los antiguos valores asignados

Answer (score 1):

> Me gustaría un código o función simple para poder convertir un tipo de dato numérico (como `int`, `float`, `long`) a un `char*` para después concatenarlo con otro `char*`.

Para empezar, debemos aclarar algunas cosas:

- Los punteros a carácter (`char*`) no se concatenan.
- Has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), así que deberías usar las herramientas de ese lenguaje.

La manera más fácil de concatenar datos en C++ es usando flujos de datos:

```
std::cout << numero << " texto " << otro_numero;
```

Comment: Concatenarlos en una variable de tipo char*